# Calculated PivotFields in the Excel Javascript add-in API

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I'm attempting to create a pivot table through the Excel Javascript API, based off of some old code. With VBA, I could write something like

```vb
Worksheets(1).PivotTables(1).CalculatedFields.Add "PxS", _ 
 "= Product * Sales"
```

to add a calculated field to a pivot table. I can't find an equivalent through the excel javascript api and I'm not sure if it just hasn't been added yet, or if I'm missing a feature somewhere.

The closest thing I've found is [ShowAsRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.showasrule?view=excel-js-preview), but I don't *think* the functionality there is equivalent (you can't use a custom formula)

Answer (score 0):

can you check the doc of Add rows and columns to a PivotTable segment in the url https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-pivottables ? A workaround is creating a new column with like C=A*B, and add C directly

Comment: The problem with this is how fields are aggregated in a pivot table. So if I calculate something like a percentage at a bottom level of the hierarchy, at the top level it will be > 100% but that metric won't be accurate.